# psycopg2 copy from csv error

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

This fails with messages: could not open file ""C:/Users/Xxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxx/c.csv"" for reading: Invalid argument. I have tried to write :'{}' and {}. I have absolutely no idea what to do

```
csv_full = 'C:/Users/Xxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxx/c.csv'
cur.execute(
        sql.SQL("""copy {} FROM '{}'
        HEADER DELIMITER ',' CSV""").format(psycopg2.sql.Identifier(table_name),psycopg2.sql.Identifier(csv_full)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name is not an identifier. It should be a normal (string) literal. Use placeholders for that:

```
csv_full = 'C:/Users/Xxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxx/c.csv'
query = sql.SQL("""copy {} FROM %s
    HEADER DELIMITER ',' 
    CSV""").format(psycopg2.sql.Identifier(table_name))
cur.execute(query, (csv_full,))
```

Please note that the `%s` is not meant for Python %-formatting.